# Context processors and manual rendering

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my Django app I need to refresh part of a page via an Ajax call. The associated view returns a `JsonResponse` object, where one key in the context is the re-rendered HTML.

Something like this:

```
def myview(request):
    ...
    tmpl8 = template.loader.get_template('page-table.html')
    new_body = tmpl8.render({ 'rows': MyModel.custom_query() })
    context = { 'new_body': new_body,
                'other_info': other_information_for_javascript }
    return JsonResponse(request, context)
```

Now, I also have context processors which add generic information. Some of this is needed in rendering `page-table.html`.

Unfortunately, context-processors don't get invoked by a bare `Template.render()`. They are invoked on the returned `JsonResponse` object, but it's too late by then as I've already rendered the template.

In Django 1.9 you can supply a `RequestContext` to `Template.render` and things go well - except for a Deprecation Warning appearing in the console. Django 1.10 insists that `Template.render` be given a `dict`.

So, the best I've been able to come up with is this:

```
from .context_processors import my_context_processor

def myview(request):
    ...
    tmpl8 = template.loader.get_template('page-table.html')

    render_context = { 'rows': MyModel.custom_query() }
    render_context.update(my_context_processor(request))
    new_body = tmpl8.render(render_context)

    context = { 'new_body': new_body,
                'other_info': other_information_for_javascript }
    return JsonResponse(request, context)
```

Basically explicitly invoking the processor.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what the [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render) documentation says:

> Template.render(context=None, request=None)
>   Renders this template
>   with a given context.
>
> If context is provided, it must be a dict. If it isn’t provided, the
>   engine will render the template with an empty context.
>
> If request is provided, it must be an HttpRequest. Then the engine
>   must make it, as well as the CSRF token, available in the template.
>   How this is achieved is up to each backend.
>
> Here’s an example of the search algorithm. For this example the
>   TEMPLATES setting is:

The second parameter is the request! So we have

```
 new_body = tmpl8.render(render_context, request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `request` to `render()` method:

```
new_body = tmpl8.render({ 'rows': MyModel.custom_query() }, request)
```